# compare characters in a string to another string?

Tags: python

this is my code right now,
i want to know how to code something like

[image: this] to turn out like

[image: that] when user gives an input.
A means the number is in the string, and in the right place, but B means its in the string but wrong place.
i also want to know how to check for duplicate letters, or "numbers" in this case, in a string.

```
import random
 


def main():
    n = int(input("Please enter the number of digits of the number: "))
    while n > 10 or n < 1: 
        n = int(input("Your number is not between 1 and 10, please reenter: ")) 
    finalnum = generatenum(n) #this is for A (generates n digit number)
    print(finalnum)
    counter = 1
    question = "What is your valid guess #" + str(counter) +  " of this " + str(n) + " digit number? " 
    guess = input(question)
    while guess != finalnum:
        if len(guess) < len(finalnum) or len(guess) > len(finalnum):
            print("Please enter the correct number of digits")
            counter += 1
            guess = input("What is your valid guess #" + str(counter) +  " of this " + str(n) + " digit number? ")
        if #???
            guess = input("What is your valid guess #" + str(counter) +  " of this " + str(n) + " digit number? ")
    print("Congratulations! You successfully guessed the correct number!")
    #for i in guess:
            

    
                

def generatenum(n):
    total = ""
    while len(total) < n:
        strnum = str(random.randrange(0,10))
        if strnum not in total: 
            total += strnum
        
    return total




main()
```

Comment: Simple test for duplicates is `if len(somesequence) == len(set(somesequence)):`. I'm not clear on what you're asking for the rest of the question though.

Comment: Please post text as text, rather than images.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to go through the guess char by char and check each one, that's why we use a for-loop:

```
while guess != finalnum:    
    if len(guess) < len(finalnum) or len(guess) > len(finalnum):
        print("Please enter the correct number of digits")
        counter += 1
        guess = input("What is your valid guess #" + str(counter) +  " of this " + str(n) + " digit number? ")
        continue # skips the for-loop

    for i, char in enumerate(guess)::
        if char == finalnum[i]: # A
            # replace with your logic
            print(char + " is in the right position")

        elif char in finalnum: # B
            # replace with your logic
            print(char + " is in the wrong position but in finalnum")
```

Comment: Don't use `for i in range(len(guess)):` this way. Instead use `for ch, i in enumerate(guess):`. Each character in `guess` is in turn represented by `ch` and you have `i` for indexing `finalnum` in a cleaner fashion.

Comment: @Chris Surely you meant `for i, ch in enumerate(guess):` (not `ch, i`) since the first item in the tuple is the index, and the rest is elements from the iterable.

Comment: You're right. I've been dealing with a different language that does the opposite, and my brain is (occasionally) fallible.

Comment: @Chris I thought about using `enumerate`, but chose not to because the OP might not know it and get confused.

Comment: Hey, being confused is the first step in not being confused.

Comment: ok, changed it. here ya go